# RSA encrypt with Pycrypto OAEP and decrypt with plain old Java

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa, pycrypto

I RSA encrypt an AES key using PyCrypto PKCS_OAEP. The OAEP uses SHA1 and MGF1 (defaults).

I am trying to get a Cipher instance in Java which matches my PyCrypto encryption param spec.

I see that the SHA1/MGF1 padding is fine, BUT totally unsure about the cipher mode. I assume it is ECB but can someone help here. Decryption is failing. I can provide the errors when I get to work, but till then there may be a trivial answer that will save any  more discussion.

Comment: RSA can only be used in ECB mode. You need to show us how you are attempting to perform the decryption.

Comment: Public key ciphers are not used in any mode of operation, so the technically correct term is "NONE", though the JCE does accept "ECB" as a synonym for legacy compatibility reasons. The string to pass to `Cipher.getInstance()` should be `"RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding"`.

Comment: @ntoskrnl sounds like an answer to me ... don't become CodesInChaos and use the answer button :P

Comment: Done. All good. Thx for the answers

Comment: @owlstead Posted comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Public key ciphers are not used in any mode of operation, so the technically correct term is "NONE", though the JCE does accept "ECB" as a synonym for legacy compatibility reasons. The string to pass to `Cipher.getInstance()` should be `"RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding"`.

Comment: SunJCE (1.7.40) seems to not have None as an option.
RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Paddinng works fine